# How to turn an object into a request in C#

Tags: c#, url, get

My Model, example:

```
public class Obj
    {
        public Obj()
        { }
        public int? IdRestricao { get; set; }
        public int? IdTipoRestringido { get; set; }
        public string CodRestringido { get; set; }
        public string NomeRestringido { get; set; }
        public int? IdTipoRestricao { get; set; }
        public string CodRestricao { get; set; }
        public string NomeRestricao { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PeriodoInicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PeriodoFim { get; set; }
        public int? IdStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Request

```
www.url.com.br?IdRestricao=1&IdTipoRestringido=2&CodRestringido=3&NomeRestringido=4&IdTipoRestricao=5&CodRestricao=6&NomeRestricao=7&PeriodoInicio=8&PeriodoFim=9
```

code:

```
var model = obj.*tostring()*// 
something like    
var request = new RestRequest($"/api/{**model**}", Method.GET);
```

edit1:

I'm wondering if there is a library or something that transforms my object in my request as in the examples above

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `ToString` to format the data from the `Obj` class into `GET` parameters.

You could write a utility function to convert all object properties into `nameof` and the associated `value` into `key-value pairs`.

Something such as this answer to convert your `Obj` into a dictionary, and then another method to convert the dictionary into `Prop=value` could be done.

For a one off something like this would be suitable:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"IdRestricao={IdRestricao}&IdTipoRestringido={IdTipoRestringido}&CodRestringido={CodRestringido}...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to what I was looking for, it follows below in case anyone needs it in the future

```
private static string ToQueryString(this object request, string separator = ",")
        {
            if (request == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

            // Get all properties on the object
            var properties = request.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.CanRead)
                .Where(x => x.GetValue(request, null) != null)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(request, null));

            // Get names for all IEnumerable properties (excl. string)
            var propertyNames = properties
                .Where(x => !(x.Value is string) && x.Value is IEnumerable)
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .ToList();

            // Concat all IEnumerable properties into a comma separated string
            foreach (var key in propertyNames)
            {
                var valueType = properties[key].GetType();
                var valueElemType = valueType.IsGenericType
                                        ? valueType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                                        : valueType.GetElementType();
                if (valueElemType.IsPrimitive || valueElemType == typeof(string))
                {
                    var enumerable = properties[key] as IEnumerable;
                    properties[key] = string.Join(separator, enumerable.Cast<object>());
                }
            }

            // Concat all key/value pairs into a string separated by ampersand
            return string.Join("&", properties
                .Select(x => string.Concat(
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Key), "=",
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(x.Value.ToString()))));
        }
```